# Gsutil: Error with "du" command

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, transfer, gsutil

When I run this command then it works (I get as expected the size of the directory):

```
C:\Users>python c:\gsutil\gsutil du -sh gs://bucket/Project/Zotero
```

But if I run this command , then I get the error below:

```
C:\Users>python c:\gsutil\gsutil du -sh gs://bucket/Project/Zotéro DB
CommandException: "du" command does not support "file://" URLs. Did you mean to use a gs:// URL?
```

Is this because there is a space/accent in the URL in the second example ? If yes, is there a way to escape the space/accent so I can run the du command without changing the folder name?

Answer (score 1):

For the space: you can add `"` before and after your URL like this:

```
C:\Users>python c:\gsutil\gsutil du -sh gs:"//bucket/Project/Zotero DB"
```

or like this

```
C:\Users>python c:\gsutil\gsutil du -sh gs://bucket/Project/"Zotero DB"
```

However, the `é` wont' work, so you replace it in your folder name:

> CommandException: Invalid encoding for argument (...). Arguments must
>   be decodable as Unicode. NOTE: the argument printed above replaces the
>   problematic characters with a hex-encoded printable representation.
>   For more details (including how to convert to a gsutil-compatible
>   encoding) see `gsutil help encoding`.

Comment: There's no problem with é. The only thing needed is to quote the argument: C:\Users>python c:\gsutil\gsutil du -sh "gs://bucket/Project/Zotéro DB"